# Translate XPath to JXPath

Tags: xpath, jxpath

I've got the following XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <CreateReservation>
           <NewReservation>
              <Profile op="D">
                 <ProfileID>ID</ProfileID>
                 <ProfileType>TYPE</ProfileType>
              </Profile>
              <Number>123456</Number>
           </NewReservation>
```

marshalled with JAXB from `CreateReservation` class in the following way:

```
CreateReservation request = new CreateReservation("123456", "D");
String xpathExpr = "boolean(//*[local-name()='CreateReservationRQ']//@op='D')"
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreateReservation.class);
marshaller = context.createMarshaller();    
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.newDocument();
marshaller.marshal(request, document); //line creates xml presented above

//EVALUATION
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xPath.evaluate(xpathExpr, document, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN); //line evaluates xpath and returns true
```

Summing everythig up, presented code marshalls `CreateReservation` class, create corresponding XML out of it, and with xpath expression checks if created xml has any `<CreateReservation>` node, which has any child with `op="D"` attribute. The check is done with the following xpath expression:

```
boolean(//*[local-name()='CreateReservationRQ']//@op='D')
```

The condition works fine, fot presented code sample. Right now I would like to get rid of unnecessary marshalling of `CreateReservation` class. To do so, I would like to switch from JAXB to JXPath:

```
PathContext jXPathContext = JXPathContext.newContext(obj);
Object obj = jXPathContext.getValue(CONDITION);
if (obj != null) {
   //code should behave exactly the same, as my previous model
}
```

`obj`- member of `CreateReservation` class (it's structure is exactly the same as presented in xml above)

`CONDITION`- my JXPath query

The idea is, that line:

```
  Object obj = jXPathContext.getValue(CONDITION);
```

Returns any node, when `CreateREservation` class has `op` field equal to 'D'. If no node is present null is returned. Functionally code should behave exactly the same as previously. Could you tell me how my `CONDITION` should look like?

Comment: Which element should be returned in case the *condition* is fulfilled? (*condition*: *"there is any <CreateReservation> node, having any child with op="D" attribute"*)

Comment: Also, skimming through [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/users-guide.html#XPath_Axes_And_Object_Graphs) article, seem to me that JXPath's `getValue()` can accept standard XPath expression CMIIW

Comment: Provided the condition is fullfilled, any node can be returned. By knowing if returned value is null or not, I can simply check if confition was fullfilled.

Unfortunatelly JXPathContext.getValue() does not accept all XPath expressions. E.g. xpath functions like: local-name() are not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic xpath to object implementation you can have a look into this.

**Example 1: JavaBean Property Access**

JXPath can be used to access properties of a JavaBean.

```
 public class Employee {
    public String getFirstName(){
       ...
    }
 }

 Employee emp = new Employee();
 JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(emp);
 String fName = (String)context.getValue("firstName");
```

In this example, we are using JXPath to access a property of the emp bean. In this simple case the invocation of JXPath is equivalent to invocation of getFirstName() on the bean.

**Example 2: Nested Bean Property Access**

JXPath can traverse object graphs:

```
 public class Employee {
    public Address getHomeAddress(){
       ...
    }
 }
 public class Address {
    public String getStreetNumber(){
       ...
    }
 }

 Employee emp = new Employee();
 ...

 JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(emp);
 String sNumber = (String)context.getValue("homeAddress/streetNumber");
```

In this case XPath is used to access a property of a nested bean.
A property identified by the xpath does not have to be a "leaf" property. For instance, we can extract the whole Address object in above example:

```
Address addr = (Address)context.getValue("homeAddress");
```

**Example 3: Setting Properties**

JXPath can be used to modify property values.

```
 public class Employee {
    public Address getAddress() {
       ...
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
       ...
    }
 }

 Employee emp = new Employee();
 Address addr = new Address();
 ...

 JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(emp);
 context.setValue("address", addr);
 context.setValue("address/zipCode", "90190");
```

**Example 4: Creating objects**
*JXPath can be used to create new objects. First, create a subclass of AbstractFactory and install it on the JXPathContext. Then call createPathAndSetValue() instead of "setValue". JXPathContext will invoke your AbstractFactory when it discovers that an intermediate node of the path is null. It will not override existing nodes.*

```
public class AddressFactory extends AbstractFactory {
    public boolean createObject(JXPathContext context,
               Pointer pointer, Object parent, String name, int index){
     if ((parent instanceof Employee) && name.equals("address"){
       ((Employee)parent).setAddress(new Address());
       return true;
     }
     return false;
   }
 }

 JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(emp);
 context.setFactory(new AddressFactory());
 context.createPathAndSetValue("address/zipCode", "90190");
```

For detail help look into this link: [JxPath Tutorial](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jxpath/JXPathContext.html)